# EncodeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I recently updated my version of django from 1.2.5 to 1.7. Once done, all new transactions on my app were working as expected. However whenever I try to access a pickled object, I get the error

`EncodeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'`

Here is the error thrown

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/foo/bar/gateway/baseGateway.py", line 108, in queueMessage
    eng.processMessage(msgRow)
  File "/foo/bar/engine/processor.py", line 101, in processMessage
    tasks.deliverMessage.apply_async(args=[foo, bar], queue='message-deliver')
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 555, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 353, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 161, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 237, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 356, in pickle_dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 113, in __reduce__
    return super(QuerySet, self).__reduce__()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 84, in _reduce_ex
    dict = getstate()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __getstate__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 967, in _fetch_all
    if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
EncodeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'
```

Looking at some of the solutions offered online and by django [here](http://jj.isgeek.net/2013/04/django-queryset-object-has-no-attribute-_prefetch_related_lookups/) and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.django.scm/89402), I cleared the sessions table in django to no avail.The error still persists. I use memcache in my application too and i cleared that. I also use celery.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Without your code it's hard to find what's wrong.

Comment: From django documentaion it seems the bug is caused by the upgrade where the attribute _prefetch_related_lookups was introduced where it did not exist. Also from the error log, seems the code is thrown at a django leval not on my code. I could however still post the code if needbe]

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing a related issue when trying to change a queryset on a model form within a view. The error was:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'
```

forms.py

```py
class S1Form(forms.ModelForm):
  library = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset = Library.objects.all(),
    to_field_name = 'title',
    required = True,
    widget = forms.Select(
      attrs = {
        'class': 'custom-select'}
    ),
    disabled = False,
    empty_label = 'Select a library'
  )
```

views.py

```py
class FilteredSpectraSearchListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
  ...
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['sform'] = S1Form()
    context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = None
    if <something>:
      context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = <...>
    elif <something-else>:
      context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = <...>
    return context
```

The goal was to have an empty queryset initially which is later changed based on a few conditional statments. The problem was that the conditional `"<something>"` was not firing and `None` remained the queryset. The solution was simply to provide an empty queryset rather than `None` for this case:

```py
    ...
    context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = Library.objects.none()
    if <something>:
      context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = <...>
    elif <something-else>:
      context['sform'].fields['library'].queryset = <...>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling giving us a results

resetting sessions app fixed the issue (at least for the moment...)
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18674

The problem is the Sessions, I had to delete them all for it to work. Addtionally I changed the settings SECRET_KEY so all sessions don’t validate.

http://jj.isgeek.net/2013/04/django-queryset-object-has-no-attribute-_prefetch_related_lookups/

Answer (score 0):

You have some serialized data from Django < 1.4, and Kombu tries to deserialize it in your current Django version.

I don't know where Kombu saves its serialized data, but that's where you should look. You should either delete the stale data, or if you need to keep the data, manually change it to match your current Django version.